# unpickling a dictionary of encoded words

Tags: python, dictionary, utf-8, pickle

I have created a dictionary (which as Keys has encoded words in utf-8) :

```
import os.path
import codecs
import pickle
from collections import Counter

wordDict = {}

def pathFilesList():
     source='StemmedDataset'
     retList = []
     for r, d, f in os.walk(source):
         for files in f:
             retList.append(os.path.join(r, files))
return retList

# Starts to parse a corpus, it counts the frequency of each word and
# the date of the data (the date is the file name.) then saves words
# as keys of dictionary and the tuple of (freq,date) as values of each
# key.
def parsing():
    fileList = pathFilesList()
    for f in fileList:
        date_stamp = f[15:-4]
        print "Processing file: " + str(f)
        fileWordList = []
        fileWordSet = set()
        # One word per line, strip space. No empty lines.
        fw = codecs.open(f, mode = 'r' , encoding='utf-8')
        fileWords = Counter(w for w in fw.read().split())
        # For each unique word, count occurance and store in dict.
        for stemWord, stemFreq in fileWords.items():
            if stemWord not in wordDict:
                wordDict[stemWord] = [(date_stamp, stemFreq)]
            else:
                wordDict[stemWord].append((date_stamp, stemFreq))
        # Close file and do next.
        fw.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Parse all files and store in wordDict.
    parsing()

output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')


print "Dumping wordDict of size {0}".format(len(wordDict))
pickle.dump(wordDict, output)

output.close()
```

when I unpickle the pickled data , and query this dictionary I can't query alphabetical words , even words of which I'm sure they're in the dictionary,it always returns false , but for the numeric query , it works fine. here is how I unpickle the data and query :

```
    pkl_file=codecs.open('data.pkl' , 'rb' )
    wd=pickle.load(pkl_file)
    pprint.pprint(wd)    #to make sure the wd is correct and it has been created 
    print type(wd)      #making sure of the type of data structure 
    pkl_file.close()

   #tried lots of other ways to query like if wd.has_key('some_encoded_word')
   value= None
   inputList= ['اندیمشک' , '16' , 'درحوزه' ]
   for i in inputList :
       if i in wd :     
           value = wd[i]
           print value
       else:    
           print 'False'
```

here is my output

```
pa@pa:~/Desktop$ python unpickle.py 
False
[('2000-05-07', 5), ('2000-07-05', 2)]
False
```

so I'm quite sure there's something wrong with the encoded words .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using codecs.open. That function is specifically for opening a text file and automatically decoding the data to Unicode. (As a side note, you usually want io.open, not codecs.open, even for that case.)

To open a binary file to be passed as bytes to something like pickle.load, just use the builtin open function, not codecs.open.

Meanwhile, it usually makes things simpler to use Unicode strings throughout your program, and only use byte strings at the edges, decoding input as soon as you get it and encoding output as late as possible.

Also, you have literal Unicode characters in non-Unicode string literals. Never, ever, ever do this. That's the surest way to create invisible mojibake strings. Always use Unicode literals (like u'abc' instead of 'abc') when you have non-ASCII characters.

Plus, if you use non-ASCII characters in the source, always use a coding declaration (and of course make sure your editor is using the same encoding you put in the coding declaration),

Also, keep in mind that == (and dict lookup) may not do what you want for Unicode. If you have a word stored in NFC, and look up the same word in NFD, the characters won't be identical even though they represent the same string. Without knowing the exact strings you're using and how they're represented it's hard to know if this is a problem in your code, but it's pretty common with, e.g., Mac programs that get strings out of filenames or Cocoa GUI apps.